# How to set sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox default to false inside form class?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, symfony1

I've got a form class with a checkbox widget:

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
  'status' => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(array('value_attribute_value' => 1)),
  // various other widgets
));
```

Is there a way to set this checkbox to unticked from inside the form class (it's checked by default)? I can't seem to get anything to work. I found something on Google that this might be a Symfony bug that just hasn't been fixed but I'm refusing to believe it.

Setting it from the action works fine:

```
$this->form->setDefault('status', false);
```

... but I'd prefer not to have it there.

Comment: Didn't simply `$this->setDefault('status', false)` work? Did you try setting the value of the field to `false`?

Comment: Bizarre... it does work trying it now again. I've tried it several times over the past days and just must have been doing something wrong somewhere. Thanks.... if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Question will stay hanging otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the default value at the end of the `configure()` method of your form, it should work :

```
$this->setDefault('status', false);
```